# Return position of selected row in NSOutlineView

Tags: macos, cocoa, nsoutlineview, nspopover

I have an NSOutlineView which when a row in the outline view is double-clicked, an NSPopover is displayed using the following code:

```
-(void)doubleClick:(id)nid{
    NSLog(@"Test double click");
    [_popover showRelativeToRect:[nid bounds] ofView:nid preferredEdge:NSMaxXEdge];
}
```

The code works fine but places the popover in the middle of the vertical height of the outline view. I would like the popup to appear next to the row which is selected (double-clicked) in the outline view. Is there a call I can make to the Outline View to return the position of the selected row? I couldn't seem to find such a method in the documentation. Clearly I would replace [nid bounds] which such a call. Else, any other suggestions of how I could work around this would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't forget that `NSOutlineView` inherits from `NSTableView`. You're looking for `-frameOfCellAtColumn:row:`. The column is probably 0. The row you can obtain with `-selectedRow`.

If your outline view is view-based, you could also pass the row view (`-rowViewAtRow:makeIfNecessary:`) and `NSZeroRect` for the rect to `-showRelativeToRect:...`, so it automatically tracks the row.

Comment: That is exactly what I was after. Thank you Ken, greatly appreciated!